# How do you generate a C++ file containing the RLE compressed data from a directory of bitmap files?

Tags: c++, bitmap, embedded, compression, bmp

I'm working in an embedded environment, using C++ and IAR Embedded Workbench IDE. The interface is a touchscreen and all the graphics for this screen are bitmap files in a particular directory. Somehow these bitmap files are put into a gigantic .cpp file. There are around 200 (relatively small) bitmap files and the .cpp file which contains everything is 122,000 lines long!

All the information in this file is RLE8 compressed. I can't imagine this file wasn't automatically generated. My question is how? Am I really going to have to write my own program to do that because that's what the original programmer must have done? I'm hoping not to have to reinvent the wheel.

Here's an example from a tiny 9x23 image.

```
static GUI_CONST_STORAGE unsigned char acNumberBitDiameterWhiteOnGreyPeriod[] = {
  /* RLE: 164 Pixels @ 000,000*/ 164, 0x38,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 002,018*/ 1, 0x68,
  /* RLE: 003 Pixels @ 003,018*/ 3, 0xA0,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 006,018*/ 1, 0x60,
  /* RLE: 004 Pixels @ 007,018*/ 4, 0x38,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 002,019*/ 1, 0xA0,
  /* RLE: 003 Pixels @ 003,019*/ 3, 0xF8,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 006,019*/ 1, 0x80,
  /* RLE: 004 Pixels @ 007,019*/ 4, 0x38,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 002,020*/ 1, 0xA0,
  /* RLE: 003 Pixels @ 003,020*/ 3, 0xF8,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 006,020*/ 1, 0x80,
  /* RLE: 004 Pixels @ 007,020*/ 4, 0x38,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 002,021*/ 1, 0xA0,
  /* RLE: 003 Pixels @ 003,021*/ 3, 0xF8,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 006,021*/ 1, 0x80,
  /* RLE: 004 Pixels @ 007,021*/ 4, 0x38,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 002,022*/ 1, 0x68,
  /* RLE: 003 Pixels @ 003,022*/ 3, 0xA0,
  /* RLE: 001 Pixels @ 006,022*/ 1, 0x60,
  /* RLE: 002 Pixels @ 007,022*/ 2, 0x38,


  0};  /* 42 bytes for 207 pixels */

const GUI_BITMAP CBMP::m_bmNumberBitDiameterWhiteOnGreyPeriod = {
  9, /* XSize */
  23, /* YSize */
  9, /* BytesPerLine */
  GUI_COMPRESS_RLE8, /* BitsPerPixel */
  acNumberBitDiameterWhiteOnGreyPeriod,   /* Pointer to picture data (indices) */
  (const GUI_LOGPALETTE*)NULL,   /* Pointer to palette */
  GUI_DRAW_RLE_GRAY8
};
```

Images that aren't grayscale also include a color palette. Any suggestions as to how I can generate this file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It turns out the contractor we used did in fact write a program that compressed all the bitmap files into this .cpp file so I will have to get a hold of that program or roll my own. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Welcome to the world of embedded programming.  Half of my programming effort is host side tools that convert things from one format to another

Comment: When you say *"All the information in this file is RLE8 compressed."* do you mean the C file or the original image files?  There are plenty of programs for converting arbitrary binary data files to C array source code, such as http://www.deadnode.org/sw/bin2h/ - Google "binary to C".  If the source data is not already RLE get or write a tool to encode in your specific format and convert in two steps.  Writing the code to do both is not that hard.